# Namespacing in Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a timer in Javascript and I have a specific issue with how I'm implementing it.

Right now  it's like this

```
function CountUpTimer(seconds,name,targetId,submitButtonId){
this.time = seconds; 
this.currentTime = 0;
this.minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
this.submitButtonId = submitButtonId;

this.seconds = seconds - this.minutes*60;
this.currentSeconds = 0;
this.currentMinutes = 0; 
this.targetId = targetId;
this.name = name;
this.isPaused = false; 
this.init = function(){
    setInterval(this.name + ".tick()",1000);
}

this.pause = function(){
    this.isPaused = true;
}
this.unpause = function(){
    this.isPaused = false; 
}
this.tick = function(){
    if(this.isPaused == false){
    if(this.currentTime <= this.time){
        if(this.currentSeconds == 59){
            this.currentSeconds = 0;
            this.currentMinutes++; 
        }
        this.updateTimer();
        this.currentTime++;
        this.currentSeconds++;
    } else{
        this.endTiming();
    }
}
}
```

Now, the problem with this is that I can't dynamically create CountUpTimer objects, because I need to know the name of the variable that I am assigning to that object. Is there some way I can work around this - so let's say something like

```
setInterval(this.tick(),1000);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using callback, you lose the context at execution.
You should use `bind` to keep the context.

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this),1000);
```

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Note that `Function.bind` is a relatively new feature and not supported in many browsers.

Comment: [Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/weWqe/) that I created for myself then realized you are correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.init = function(){
   var self = this;
   setInterval(self.tick(),1000);
}
```

Keep the reference to original object, because using this in setInterval will be in the wrong object context (document).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function() {
    self.tick()
}, 1000);
```

Or use `Function.bind` if you are fine with non-legacy support.